# Trouble with Image name in php

Tags: php, php-gd

In my project I've given site logo name as `"banner_".time()` after doing certain manipulations on image.Image is uploaded successfully with specified name in destination folder. The problem is image is not displaying on the site,image content is missing and just showing 1x1 length.I've other images all uploading and displaying without any issues in the same folder after doing certain image manipulations. I thought it might problem with specified name so I've changed `"banner_".time()` "to `site_logo_".time()`,its working fine after changing the name.My question is "is there any restrictions on image names in php ?" or the word "banner" should not use in php for image names ? I'm using kohana framework for my project.

Comment: `is there any restrictions on image names in php?` No There isn't

Comment: Show code please. Are you saving the image when it's uploaded as "banner".time(), then calling it again with "banner".time()? Cause the time will be different in each case... Please clarify the question.